# Joomla K2 articles redirect

Tags: k2, sef, redirect

I have a lot of URLs like this: www.mywebsite.com/blog/item/1021-le-foreste.html that becomes, after SEF changes, like this: www.mywebsite.com/blog/le-foreste.html How can I write an .htaccess rule that say something like: where you find an URL with "item" word and ID number redirect to the same URL without "item" word and ID number, please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to the very beginning of your .htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /blog/item/(\d+)-(.*) /blog/$2
```

Explanation:

- This part `(\d+)` matches any number immediately after `/blog/item/`
- This part `(.*)` matches anything after the first dash.
- `$2` represents what `(.*)` matches, which is anything after the number and the hyphen (note that `$1` will be the number, which is 1021 in the case of your example above)

Comment: It works, thank you.